# Select one document with array with limited number of elements

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I have the following structure of the Room type:

```
type Room struct {
   Id          bson.ObjectId       `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   Title       string              `json:"title" bson:"title"`
   Description string              `json:"description" bson:"description,omitempty"`
   Type        string              `json:"type" bson:"type,omitempty"`
   AdminId     bson.ObjectId       `json:"admin_id" bson:"admin_id"`
   CreatedOn   time.Time           `json:"created_on" bson:"created_on"`
   Messages    []Message           `json:"messages" bson:"messages,omitempty"`}
```

The type struct Message is embedded, which has the following structure

```
type Message struct {
   Id       bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
   Text     string          `json:"text" bson:"text"`
   Author       Author          `json:"author" bson:"author"`
   CreatedOn    time.Time   `json:"createdon" bson:"created_on"`
   Reply        []Message   `json:"reply" bson:"reply,omitempty"`}
```

Using this code I can extract all the fields of the collection.

```
room := &Room{}
roomsCollection := session.DB(config.Data.DB.Database).C("Rooms")
err := roomsCollection.Find(bson.M{"_id": room_id}).One(room)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
    return nil, err
}
```

This gives the rooms with all the messages in the given documents. 
The question is, can I limit the length of nested `Messages` array in each document?

Comment: Basically you need to use [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) with your selector. So something like `roomsCollection.Find(bson.M{"_id": room_id})).Select(bson.M{
    "messages": bson.M{
        "$slice": 5}
    }
).One(room)` should help.

Comment: @Veeram Well, I did not know about $slice, but it solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution was really simple. To perform this we can use $slice.
The result query will be as following:

```
roomsCollection.Find(bson.M{"_id": room_id})).Select(bson.M{ "messages": bson.M{ "$slice": 5} } ).One(room)
```

Special thanks to @Veeram for correct answer.

Comment: You may also use [Collection.FindId()](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.FindId) to make it simpler: `roomscollection.FindId(room_id).One(...`.